# Reading result data set of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedure

I'm creating aspx form generator from stored procedure, I have stored procedure like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OU_Test_ALL]
@ID_Login uniqueidentifier = null,
@ID int = null
AS
BEGIN

declare @Error int, @Message varchar(500), @SQL varchar(max)
set @Message = 'Error'

exec @Error=dbo.CheckPermissions @ID_Login=@ID_Login, @ID=@ID, @ID_Action='OU_Test_ALL'
begin
  goto FAILED
end

select
        OU_Test.Value1Int,
        OU_Test.Value2Varchar,
        OU_Test.Value3Bit,
        OU_Test.Value4Varchar,
        OU_Test.Value5Int
from OU_Test
where (@ID is null or OU_Test.ID=@ID)

return 0

FAILED:
raiserror (@Message, 16, 1)
return 1

END
```

and I need to read result without calling it.

I was able to get some metadata in Management Studio using

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
exec OU_Test_ALL
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

, but I can't read this metadata in my C# application.

Is there any way to read result columns without calling stored procedure?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: your question is not very clear - What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I just want to read possible output columns (Value1Int, Value2Varchar, ...) and its datatype without calling procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to call your `stored procedure`:

```
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET FMTONLY ON; exec sp_sptest; SET FMTONLY OFF;"
                                       , connection);

    command.Connection.Open();

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
    resultTable.Load(reader);

    command.Connection.Close();
```

Columns are filed and you can see column types, names etc. Rows are not filled.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx) method. Call your stored proc using `SET FMTONLY ON;` and the structure will be available in the `DataTable` returned by `GetSchemaTable()`.

Or, the [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx) method of `SqlCommand` has an overload that handles the `SET FMTONLY` for you if you pass in the [CommandBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) of `SchemaOnly`.

Something along the lines of:

```cs
SqlDataReader _Reader = null;

_Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
DataTable _Schema = _Reader.GetSchemaTable();
```